# Macro single step works when routine doesn't

Tags: vba

I have been running this macro and it come up with an 424 Object Required Error but the macro works and I get the expected result when I run it with a single step button "F8".

```
Sub FileUpload()

    Dim IEexp As InternetExplorer
      Set IEexp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IEexp.Visible = False


    IEexp.navigate "https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=lenti+a+contatto+colorate"

      Do While IEexp.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Dim inputElement As HTMLDivElement
      Set inputElement = IEexp.Document.getElementById("brs")
    MsgBox inputElement.textContent


 IEexp.Quit
    Set IEexp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The error comes up on the `Set inputElement = IEexp.Document.getElementById("brs")` line.

Comment: The error comes up on the "Set inputElement = IEexp.Document.getElementById("brs")" line

Comment: Is there any reason why the 424 error doesn't trigger the macro? Every line of the same macro flows with a F8 single step manual option producing the MsgBox result.

Comment: And what object could be required? What is the difference with single step? The  time it needs to execute. And what could be influenced by time at this code line? The Explorer-Object or the HtTMLDocument that gets loaded? So IEexp.ReadyState is too early. I think most people use :Busy, but I have prepared a class for IEexp events, where you can use DocumentCompleted event of InternetExplorer. I will share it later.

Comment: For sure it is a timing problem, I have commented the "Do While IEexp.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop" line and processed every step manually and quickly with f8(less then 1 second for each step) and it comes up with the same error on Set As line code, when instead if I process it with f8 but slowly(5 seconds each steps at least) everything flows. We defenetley need something more powerfull that can set the InternetExplorer document in every step because ReadyState doesn't work this time.

Comment: Try `Do While (IEexp.Busy OR IEexp.ReadyState <> 4): DoEvents: Loop
` for better results, but this doesn't work for all sites. My Class has still some flaws, keep patient.

Comment: I have tried to shift loop of the the do while block after the "set inputElement" line and it flows but the variable get lost and the Msg Box Line shows a "run time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' automation error". I wonder if we can disable some picky error default in order to make it run?

Comment: I have tried also a Resume next but it doesn't produce any result, we could try to loop the Resume statement until the server hooks the connection or staff like that...but it is just talking:) since the error it is not inconsequential

Comment: I have put before the set statement an Error spot line sort of:    If iputElement = Empty Then MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description and the MsgBox shows 0 errors and blank description and with the 424 one

Comment: Finally some results, just shove a:                                                     Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02")
 before Set inputElement and it works even if it slows down the process, it is handy if you loop the URL with a Do while Active.Cell <> Empty and put the variable Active.Cell as a variable on the last bit of the url like this... "www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" & Active.Cell.Value & ""   fill in the column where the cursor on the spreadsheet is located with the list of the url bits to concatenate on the macro and help yourself with a recorded macro.......

Comment: ....in order to paste the result and locate the cursor on the next url variable in the first column ...ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = inputElement.textContent
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

Answer (score 0):

You’re checking the `ReadyState` of the browser, but with some modern web pages the DOM isn’t actually updated with some objects until *at least* that point.

IE automation in VBA is quite primitive, and it sounds like in this scenario you’re trying to access a node in the DOM before it exists - despite your best efforts to wait until the browser is ready. In some cases this can literally be a matter of milliseconds out in timings.

Your quickest fix here is to simply add `Application.Wait()` in your loop to cause an actual time delay. A more elegant option might be to introduce a check in your loop and exit the loop when the desired DOM object actually exists. If you do this, there’s a danger of ending up in an infinite loop and so I would always recommend setting a maximum number of increments as a backup.